# Can't enable IIS on windows features - An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7

I'm having a problem while trying to install "Internet Information Services", I first installed IIS express, then I went to windows features, and tried to enable that so it will install it.
The issue is that after selecting that and clicking on 'ok', I'm receiving the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yafDq.png)

I tried checking for corrupted system files, but everything just seems to be fine.
I am running windows 7 ultimate x64, and I'm kinda lost, not sure what else I could try..

Also, this seems to happen with a few other features(such as WPAS) that I try to enable/disable, some of them works, some don't.
Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can see some google results about this but no solution has worked for me. Any ideas?..

Comment: In the worst case you need an in-place upgrade of Windows 7.

Comment: @LexLi Hmm what does that mean?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-perform-an-in-place-upgrade-with-windows-10/7f0b236e-3c6c-4913-9691-c4baa2a6190a Windows 7 steps are similar.

Comment: Check the following log file: "C:\windows\logs\CBS\CBS.log" immediately after Windows shows the error message